# laravel admin can access user account

Tags: php, laravel-5

i need some code or reference for laravel admin access user account but admin should not logout when he/she login to user account.

i need admin and user account login at time by admin.

i have already did following code

```
$user = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('id', $request->userid)
                    ->first();

    if (Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

but admin logs out when login to user account by user id

Comment: logging in with user and admin at same time??? how will it be possible? You can try logging in in 2 different browsers.

Comment: is there any way to do this, admin session should persistence when they login to user account

Comment: no... why do you need to login with 2 users?

Comment: Take a look at http://blog.mauriziobonani.com/easily-impersonate-any-user-in-a-laravel-application/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so, you can make some hacks to do it. 
First of all, when you log into user, you lose all references to admin, if you want to login back as admin you need to remember what was that admin... One of ways you cand do it, is to put in session the data..

```
$user = DB::table('users')
           ->where('id', $request->userid)
           ->first();
$request->session()->put('isAdmin', 1);
$request->session()->put('adminID', Auth::id());
if (Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)) {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Well now we have data about admin, but when we make a logout, we don't return to admin... So we have to do it, the easiest way to do it, is to return to admin before logout

logout function:

```
if($request->session()->pull('isAdmin', 0)){
    $id = $request->session()->pull('adminID', 0);
    if(Auth::loginUsingId($id)) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
Auth::logout();
return redirect('/');
```